# Using jqgrid on a tablet - how to get 'long touch'?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm looking at some code that needs to coexist on desktops and tablets/phones. To that end I'd like to support a 'long click' to tunnel into an item from a list.

I don't see this as a supported event on jqgrid but I'm wondering if anyone has a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity - here's the answer:

```
$( "#grid" ).mousedown( function ( event )
{
   clearTimeout( this.localtimer );
   this.localtimer = setTimeout( function()
   {
       $td = $( event.target ).closest( 'td' );
       $tr = $td.closest( 'tr.jqgrow' );
       rowid = $tr.attr( 'id' );

       console.log( "rowid: " + rowid );
   }, 2000 );
}).mouseup( function( event )
{
    clearTimeout( this.localtimer );
});
```